# IdentityServer4 shared X509 certificate at AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 endpoint as AWS Lambda and I need to share signing/validation certificate between lambda instances.

This is a current workarnound:

```
        var identityServer = services.AddIdentityServer(options => {});

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            identityServer.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }
        else
        {
            identityServer.AddSigningCredential(GetIdentityServerCertificate(Configuration));
```

and

```
    private static X509Certificate2 GetIdentityServerCertificate(
        IConfiguration configuration
    )
    {
        var pfxSecret = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CERT_PRIVATE");

        var pfxBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pfxSecret);
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxBytes);
        return certificate;
    }
```

Does AWS have any product suitable for storing certificates?

Thanks!

Comment: AWS Secrets Manager is probably the best fit.

Comment: @Luke1988 did you end up finding a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store private key of a certificate in [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/secrets-manager/). 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603278/2092344) you can find some additional inforamtion how to use AWS Secrets Manager for storing certificates.